# Checkered Pattern on Altium Traces

Tags: altium, routing, error

I'm seeing a checkered pattern on a couple traces in Altium

[image]

I'm curious as to what it might be, how to remove it, and if it might be the reason I can't save. This is the error I'm getting when I try to save.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It might help to also include an image of one of the traces in question with a wider view so we can see the entire trace.

Comment: The error is caused by exactly what it says.  You are trying to save before completing the current command, such as routing a trace, and this is not supported.  If you hit Escape a few times or any other method of terminating or completing the active command, you will not get the error when you save.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't tried that. I've tried closing and reopening altium without making any actual changes, saving copies multiple times, and deleting the entire thing and getting it back from a repository.

Answer (score 1):

You have "net color override" enabled on that specific net, and the global color override mode is active.
See [Using Color to Highlight Nets on Schematics and PCB in Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/using-net-highlight-color-schematics-pcb) for more details.

You can resolve this in two ways:

1. Toggle the global net color override mode, using F5. This disables the color override feature entirely.
2. Disable the color override for that net, which you probably have set by mistake. To do that, locate the net in the PCB panel under the "Nets" list and remove the checkmark (which should be present) next to it in the "*" column *Alternatively*, you can right-click the net name and select "Display Override/Selected Off" from the net's context menu in the PCB panel.

Answer (score 0):

The checkered pattern indicates that you have assigned a special color for this specific net (and have zoomed quite into it so it became visible).

The other issue was in issue in previous versions of Altium and is considered a bug. The other option is that you have run a script and it hasn't finished completely. That will also cause AD to be in such a strange state. In any case it makes sense to save your files and close and reopen AD.